# Replace Function not working Getting error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment from replace function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update a macro that starts by changing the name of a workbook path. When I run the code I am getting the wrong number of arguments error. I have looked over the argument but appears to me to be working correctly. Thank you in advance of any assistance!

```
Sub agetprevsectinfo()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim xx As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim newdir As String
Dim formulapth As String
Dim curmnth As String
Dim prevmnth As String
x = 0
xx = 0
y = 104
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
curmnth = wb.Sheets("Section Info").Range("N28")
prevmnth = wb.Sheets("Section Info").Range("N27")

newdir = wb.Path & "\" & replace(replace(wb.Name, curmnth, prevmnth), MonthName(CDate(curmnth)), MonthName(CDate(prevmnth)))
formulapth = wb.Path & "\[" & replace(replace(wb.Name, curmnth, prevmnth), MonthName(CDate(curmnth)), MonthName(CDate(prevmnth))) & "]"
'last chance to cancel import
If MsgBox("Import may take upto 45seconds..." & vbNewLine & "Press OK to continue", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

If Len(Dir(newdir)) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "Previous Month Tracker not found " & vbNewLine & "Please enter results manually", vbOKOnly, "Import Section"
     Exit Sub
    Else
Application.StatusBar = "Importing Section Info..." & xx & "%"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim teststr As String
    For i = 5 To 26
        If i <> 25 Then
        teststr = "='" & formulapth & "Section Info'!R" & i & "C4"
        ws.Range("D" & i).FormulaR1C1 = teststr
            If ws.Range("D" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range("D" & i).ClearContents
            Else
            ws.Range("D" & i).Value = ws.Range("D" & i).Value
            End If
        x = (x + 1)
        xx = ((x / y)) * 100
        Application.StatusBar = "Importing Section Info..." & xx & "%"
        End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 5 To 26
        If i <> 25 Then
            teststr = "='" & formulapth & "Section Info'!R" & i & "C5"
            ws.Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = teststr
            If ws.Range("E" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range("E" & i).ClearContents
            Else
            ws.Range("E" & i).Value = ws.Range("E" & i).Value
            End If
        x = (x + 1)
        xx = ((x / y)) * 100
        Application.StatusBar = "Importing Section Info..." & xx & "%"
        End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 5 To 26
        If i <> 25 Then
        teststr = "='" & formulapth & "Section Info'!R" & i & "C6"
        ws.Range("F" & i).FormulaR1C1 = teststr
        ws.Range("F" & i).Value = ws.Range("F" & i).Value
            If ws.Range("F" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range("F" & i).ClearContents
            Else
            ws.Range("F" & i).Value = ws.Range("F" & i).Value
            End If
        x = (x + 1)
        xx = ((x / y)) * 100
        Application.StatusBar = "Importing Section Info..." & xx & "%"
        End If
Next i
    For i = 5 To 26
        If i <> 25 Then
        teststr = "='" & formulapth & "Section Info'!R" & i & "C7"
        ws.Range("G" & i).FormulaR1C1 = teststr
            If ws.Range("G" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ws.Range("G" & i).ClearContents
            Else
            ws.Range("G" & i).Value = ws.Range("G" & i).Value
            End If
        x = (x + 1)
        xx = ((x / y)) * 100
        Application.StatusBar = "Importing Section Info..." & xx & "%"
        End If
Next i
MsgBox "FINISHED!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False
End If

End Sub
```

My error is in the second replace function.

[image]

Comment: Have you done any debugging of your own? Usually if you debug and mouse over the variables, you'll be alerted to something amiss. Also, your sample code doesn't provide examples of what your `curmnth` and `prevmnth` values might be.

Comment: When I step into the code I cannot even start before I get the error. Before the new year this code worked with no issues but now the code no longer works. I also added the cells referred to in the code.

Comment: The only suspicious thing I see is the `MonthName` call.  You are passing a CDate, the method is expecting a Long.  What is the value of `curmnth`?

Comment: Also a bit suspicious that `replace` is not `Replace`

Comment: Originally I did not have the CDate but based on my looking for an answer online that was what I tried to fix the issue.

Comment: Based on Tim's comment, does your code have a `replace` function some place?  One with a lower case `r` that expects more arguments?

Comment: So I tried to change to capital `Replace` but it would auto-correct to lowercase. So I made `Dim Replace` and then they capitalized. I then deleted the `Dim`. I also tried the hard code but for me I still get the same error.

Comment: Yep. Looks like somewhere you've overridden the built-in `Replace()` function with your own homegrown `replace()` function (lowercase).

Comment: That was what fixed it. Someone went in and made a Sub I did not know about... Thank you for your time. If you turn your response to an answer I will mark "answered"

Comment: Can you run a simple standalone sub which just does something like `Debug.Print Replace("Hello","H","J")`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code to this:

```
Sub agetprevsectinfo()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim xx As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim newdir As String
Dim formulapth As String
Dim curmnth As String
Dim prevmnth As String
x = 0
xx = 0
y = 104
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
curmnth = "03"  'hard-coded
prevmnth = "02" 'hard-coded

newdir = wb.Path & "\" & Replace(Replace(wb.Name, curmnth, prevmnth), MonthName(CDate(curmnth)), MonthName(CDate(prevmnth)))
formulapth = wb.Path & "\[" & Replace(Replace(wb.Name, curmnth, prevmnth), MonthName(CDate(curmnth)), MonthName(CDate(prevmnth))) & "]"
'last chance to cancel import
MsgBox (formulapth)

End Sub
```

And it works.

Everything about that code matches yours except I hard-coded `curmnth` and `prevmnth` and cut out everything after the line you say is failing.

In other words, you have not correctly identified the problem (assuming my hard-coded values are what your worksheets actually contain, but I based them on your screenshot).

I realize this is not a good "Answer," but I'm not sure how else to convey it.

Comment: This combined with your comment above helped to identify the issue. Thank you for your time!